# Django admin project distribution and management

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have core django admin project that when my customers purchase needs to be modified both in configuration and function. Each customer will have their own instance of the project installed on a different server. Currently I am using django apps to separate out the difference in clients and using settings.py to load the correct app for the correct customer.

So my questions:

Is there a industry standard/best practice/framework to customize configuration and functionality in django admin projects and distribute them?

Answer (score 0):

What would be best to do is write your core project on one side, and store it in a repository (version control). Apart from that, write your sub-applications as requirements and store/track them on separate version control.

Then, to keep everything working together and keep it all integrated, what you should do is that for different functionality, write it all in the same app, but add special settings that change the app's behavior. These settings can be stored in an independent settings_local.py that is imported at the end of your settings file, making them installation-independent, and you keep in your settings.py those that are general to all installations.